# When to use "cite" or "citation"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity

Is there a difference in choosing whether to use "cite" or "citation"? For example, when performing a bibliographic search or a bibliometric study, one finds "citations per year", "cites per document", and so forth.

Comment: The result of "citing" something is a "citation".  "Cite" is  a verb, "citation" is a noun.

Comment: Thank you, @HotLicks

Comment: Do note that some people will use "cite" rather than "citation" when speaking/writing informally.  But it's not generally proper in formal text.

Comment: @HotLicks you should make than an answer